# Wallpaper that I download

Tags: macos

How can I save a downloaded image to the folder called pictures that I see in System Preferences/Desktop & Screen Saver/Desktop?
I'm assuming that this is a good place to store images that I download for wallpaper.
Thanks
Gary

Answer (score 2):

Push the `+` at the bottom of the list:

[image]

Then select a folder or create a new one in your home folder, perhaps inside your Pictures folder.

There may be a way to put a picture inside the Apple desktop pictures folders, but this is the more standard way to go about it.